# InvalidCastExeption when trying to dim a string

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, getstring

Im having a problem when trying to run my code. Im new to stackoverflow but will try to explain my problem.

Well, i get a "InvalidCastExeption" with the explanation

> "Converson from string "Filename" to type "Integer" is not valid.

The confusing part is that FileName is a nvarchar(30) in my SQL database, and sName a string.

Look at the code, it failes at the dim sName = ...
Ps - I have tried to convert.toint / Cint, but it doesnt help. AND i want it as a string, not a integer!

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SelectrecipieDatabaseManager
    Private Const CONNECTION_STRING As String = "Data Source=RYOW701;Initial Catalog=RyReci;Integrated Security=True"
    Private connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Private command As SqlCommand = Nothing

    Public Sub RecipieHandler(ByVal Choice As String)

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        connection = New SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)

        Try
            connection.Open()


                Dim Query As String
                Query = "select *  from TbNew"
                command = New SqlCommand(Query, connection)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader

                While reader.Read

                    Dim sName = reader.GetString("FileName")

                    RecipieForm.ComboBoxRec.Items.Add(sName)
                End While



        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Finally
            connection.Close()
            connection.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method expects an ordinal number as it's parameter, not a string. Do this instead:

```
reader = command.ExecuteReader
Dim columnID As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("FileName")

While reader.Read
    Dim sName = reader.GetString(columnID)
    RecipieForm.ComboBoxRec.Items.Add(sName)
End While
```